# Converting txt to number in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanted to convert a text value in a cell to a numeric value using the `IF` function in Excel.

example:

- [cell A1] "."
- [cell A2] 10
- [cell B1] ".23"
- [cell B2] .23

The values in "" are just text values in excel, I wanted to change it into a numeric value, like change "." into 10, and change "xxxx" into xxxx.

Is there an efficient way to do so?

Comment: we need more information, sample text inputs and your outputs

Comment: please provide more info. Does A1 have both numbers and letters? Or do you only want to return the number if the whole cell is a number?

Comment: just edited the question

Comment: `0.23` as text into `0.23` as a values makes sense, but why would `.` become `10`?

Comment: I think he just picked a bad example of "." to 10 I think the point he is trying to make is that he wants to remove the quotes and convert it from a string to a number.

Comment: Voted to close as a non-programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the value you want to convert is in A1 you can use the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(TRIM(CLEAN(A1)))),VALUE(TRIM(CLEAN(A1))),"")
```

Here the functions clean and trim are removing whitespace and none printable characters. The function value converts a string to a number, and with the converted string we can check if the value is a number.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

`=TEXT(B7,"0.00")`

This will also ignore extra spaces, for example:

`'   .23`

Will return `0.23`

Although I still don't understand the "." = 10 part

For an example of `123`, this will turn into `123.00`.

Comment: Is it just me or does this turn 123 into 123. with the training decimal point? While it is a number it looks weird.

Comment: @SamPlusPlus, good point! Forgot about that. I'll change the answer. Thanks!